# colorbox auto close and reopen another iframe

Tags: jquery, colorbox

On load of a website i open a news-popup with colorbox. After a while this should close or fadeout and a new news fadeIn. Thats my code, the auto-close is working, but the reopen not. What is wrong?

```
$.fn.colorbox(
  { iframe:true, 
    innerWidth:760, 
    innerHeight:640, href:"aktuelles.php?id=33"});

setTimeout(function(){$.colorbox.remove();}, 5000);

setTimeout(function()
  {$.colorbox({
     iframe:true, 
     innerWidth:760, 
     innerHeight:640,href:"aktuelles.php?id=32"});}, 5000);
```

Thanks for any help.

best regards
thomas

Comment: may be you need to give `$.fn.` too in the `setTimeout` function..

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

```
setTimeout(function(){$.colorbox.remove();}, 5000);
```

We are completely removing `colorbox` from the document, which accordingly to the [documentation](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), we are not considering it for future use, the method you are looking for is `$.colorbox.close()`, applying it we would alter that line to:

```
setTimeout(function(){$.colorbox.close();}, 5000);
```

there are also 2 other important things, if you want the iframe to start opened we start `colorbox` with option `open` set to `true`, and as mentioned in my comment, we need to set different values for `setTimeout`, for example, to reopen the modal 5000ms after it was closed, we would need to set it's interval to `10000`

Comment: Thanks, i've changed it so close. The closing is working but the reopen afterwards not? do you have any idea?

Comment: sorry. solution found. as zzlalani mentioned above, i had to put $.fn. for the reopen ...

Comment: it's also pertinent to set 2 different timeout values, the second timeout will not wait the first one to be done, that means we might not achieve the desired effect, updated my answer